# android BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path) return null and I can't figure out why

Tags: android, file, save

I use the folowing code to take a picture and save it as a base64 string

```
public fun convertPictureResourceToBase64String(file_path: String?): String {
        val picture_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path)
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        picture_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
        val picture_byte_array = baos.toByteArray()
        return Base64.encodeToString(picture_byte_array, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    }

    @Composable
    public fun TakePictureButton(
        saveFile: (String) -> Unit,
        onPermissionIsDenied: ()->Unit = {},
        buttonAppearance: @Composable ()->Unit
    ){
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val file = context.createImageFile()
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            Objects.requireNonNull(context),
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file
        )

        val cameraLauncher = 
rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) {
            saveFile(convertPictureResourceToBase64String(uri.path))
        }

        val permissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) {
            if (it) {
                cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
            } else {
                onPermissionIsDenied()
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
                }else {
                    permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                }
            }
        ){
            buttonAppearance()
        }
    }

    private fun Context.createImageFile(): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(Date())
        val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
        val file = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            externalCacheDir      /* directory */
        )
        return file
    }
```

when I run it and click the takePicture buton it crashes because BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path) returns null any idea why it can't get the temporary file I created?

Comment: `save it as a base64 string` Well i did not look at your code yet as you could have told also where you wanna save that string. I dont know.

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path) returns null` Well then that is quite a different problem than mentioned in the subject of your post.

Comment: You should use the whole uri. Not only a part like uri.getPath();